# Proving tanh(x) is strictly increasing using tanh'(x)

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that tanh(x) is strictly increasing using tanh'(x). I know that
$$ tan(x) = \frac{sinh(x)}{cosh(x)}$$
$$ tan'(x) = \frac{sinh'(x)}{cosh'(x)}$$
$$=\frac{cosh^2(x)-sinh^2(x)}{cosh^2(x)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{cosh^2(x)}$$
And I know that $\frac{1}{cosh^2(x)}$ = $1-tanh^2(x)$. I also am aware that if a functions derivative is positive for all x that means a function is strictly increasing. Can I simply just put
\frac{1}{cosh^2(x)}>0 for all x in the real numbers, to show that tanh(x) is strictly increasing?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: But how can I prove it in detail, that $\frac{1}{cosh^2(x)}$>0?

Comment: It's quite obvious from the definition that $\cosh(x) > 0$ for all $x$, isn't it?